# Playback speed control for YouTube videos? HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube-api

I need to implement a video playback speed controller (e.g.: play the video at 1/2 speed) for youtube videos, and I'm thinking that HTML5 is currently the only way to do this (if it's even possible). I know very little about HTML5 video, but I know a lot about the youtube js API. Can anyone point me in the right direction? It's okay if the solution will only work in some browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new iframe api allows you to control the speed of the video:

[iframe api reference: Setting the playback rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_rate)

> The default playback rate is 1, which indicates that the video is playing at normal speed. Playback rates may include values like 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2.

Also:

> Calling this function does not guarantee that the playback rate will actually change.

Example code:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': function(e){
        // e.target = player
        e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
        e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
      },
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Does it support on mobile devices?Playback rate is not working on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

http://mediaelementjs.com/ is crossbrowser,uses flash or html5 depending on the browser support and has all the methods you are looking for.

Comment: I wasn't specific in the body of my question, but my question's title indicates that this needs to work for YouTube videos specifically. I don't see anything on that site that says that the player will work with YouTube videos. Also, it appears from the demos that the speed control is not implemented yet.

Comment: check this out: http://www.mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube#api and somewhere else in the site or its github project there's a really complete set of handlers that can help ypu with the speed control

Comment: Thanks for the link... and it appears that this *might* work... however, I didn't find any examples of playback speed control. The examples indicate that the feature isn't yet available.

Answer (score 2):

$('#video').playbackRate = 3.0 or
$('video').playbackRate = 3.0 depending on version