# Trying to set playback speed on youtube-ios-player-helper but nothing happens

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am building an iOS app that uses the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) library to play YouTube videos. I'm trying to set the playback speed, but nothing happens:

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    private let player = YTPlayerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        player.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(player)
        setupPlayerConstraints()

        player.load(withVideoId: "123456")
        // Tried here, but nothing change: 
        print("Available playback rates: \(String(describing: player.availablePlaybackRates()))")
        player.setPlaybackRate(2.0)
    }

}

extension PlayerViewController: YTPlayerViewDelegate {

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
        player.playVideo()
    }

    func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didChangeTo state: YTPlayerState) {
        switch (state) {
        case.playing:
            // Tried here, but again, nothing change:
            print("Available playback rates: \(String(describing: player.availablePlaybackRates()))")
            player.setPlaybackRate(2.0)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

As shown by the code above, I've tried setting playback speed after loading the video and also when player changes it's state to `playing`. In none of then the speed was changed.

Also, `player.availablePlaybackRates` returns nil in both cases (that's strange because when I watch the same video using the YouTube app, I can change the playback speed).

I know that setting the playback speed [is a suggestion to the player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackRate), but on the official YouTube app, changing the speed works for the same video that I'm trying to watch on my app.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: Don't think this is possible yet. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816248/playback-rate-not-working-on-ios-youtube-ytplayerview) to confirms it.

Comment: Oh gosh, guess you're right... And it doesn't seem they're going to fix it. Last commit was almost 2 years ago

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I solved it like this and it works well. in swift 4

1. `private` -> `public`

   ```
   private func stringFromEvaluingJavaScript(jsToExecute: String) -> String{
       Guard let result = self.webView.stringByEvaluingJavaScript (from jsToExecute) else{
       return ""
       }
   return result
   }
   ```
2. directly Execute

   ```
   playerView.stringFromEvaluingJavaScript(jsToExecute): "player.setPlaybackRate(1.5);")
   ```